# How to take String input in Structure type array using pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, structure

**When I run this code and try to input the first string in a Structure type Array, the program stops. But it seems that, there is no error in my code. What can I do now? I use Code::Blocks and GCC compiler.**

*

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i, serial, n=4;
    struct Student
    {
        char *name;
        char *id;
        int semester;
        int age;
        float cgpa;
    };
    struct Student stuArr[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        serial = i+1;
        printf("\t\tStudent No: %d\n", serial);
        printf("Input the name of Student-%d:\n", serial);
        scanf("%s", &stuArr[i].name);
        printf("Input %s's ID:\n", stuArr[i].name);
        scanf("%s", stuArr[i].id);
        printf("Input %s's semester:\n", stuArr[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &stuArr[i].semester);
        printf("Input %s's age:\n", stuArr[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &stuArr[i].age);
        printf("Input %s's CGPA:\n", stuArr[i].name);
        scanf("%f", &stuArr[i].cgpa);
    }
    float tot_cgpa=0, avg_cgpa;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tot_cgpa += stuArr[i].cgpa;
        if(stuArr[i].cgpa < 2.50)
        {
            printf("%s is in probation.\n", stuArr[i].name);
        }
        if(stuArr[i].age > 21)
        {
            printf("%s is more than 21 years old.\n", stuArr[i].name);
        }
        if(stuArr[i].semester >= 12)
        {
            printf("%s is in the last semester.\n", stuArr[i].name);
        }
    }
    avg_cgpa = tot_cgpa/10.0;
    printf("Average CGPA of %d students: %0.2f\n", n, avg_cgpa);
}
```

*

Comment: you have to allocate memory for your fields since they're `char *`. Or define real arrays.

Comment: type of `&stuArr[i].name` is `char**`, not `char*`(The memory itself occupied by the pointer is used as a storage destination of the string.) and `stuArr[i].name` isn't alocate for it.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &stuArr[i].name);` should be `scanf("%s", stuArr[i].name);` - it's only non-strings that you need the pointer to the variable you're storing the value in

Answer (score 1):

Your student name and id aren't allocated properly, they're uninitialized pointers.

You can either allocate them manually using malloc, or define them in the struct like you can see below:

```
struct Student
{
    char name[32];
    char id[32];
    int semester;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
};
```

Comment: is it possible to keep them uninitialized so as to avoid specifying the length of the string?